# Displaying Python Machine Learning Algorithm as HTML Web page

Tags: javascript, python, html, user-interface

So, as part of an assignment, I am doing player suggestions for NBA draft picks using clustering algorithm. The clustering algorithm is made in python and I want to show the result in the form of a user interface HTML web page. Is it possible to display the python output in an HTML web page.

In other words, the python code should run in the background of the HTML web page.

Just a note: I am not wanting to just import the matplotlib animations, but the whole algorithm from Python to HTML web  page such that when the user interacts with the interface the python algorithm must work in the background of the web page.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using matplotlib to display the results of the clustering algorithm, I would suggest googling the "mpld3" package. It is easy to use, and the results generated by mpld3's convenience routines can be embedded on a web page. If you choose to try mpld3 out, I think the routine you want to try is fig_to_html(). Follow the instructions on the official website and the "Quick Start Guide" for more detail!